# How to Reboot and shut down based on Windows Update Status

Tags: windows, windows-update, event-log, wmi

I am working on Schedule Tasks where I can reboot or shutdown my OS based on Windows Update status.

### My Setup

1. Run this task weekly on login.
2. This task starts `wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow`.
3. Then I have another task which checks Event Viewer for `System:WindowsUpdateClient:21`, which is the only link I have found and if I see this I reboot.

### What I would like

1. Reboot when `wuauclt` says update requires reboot.
2. After reboot if more updates need to be installed, it proceeds with that.
3. If now it says all updates done no more update require or no reboot required with the current updates and `wuauclt` has done it's job. Then I want to shutdown the VM.

### What I need help with

How to correctly identify that a reboot is required or no more reboots are required and no more updates are pending?

### Comments

1. Event Viewer : System:WindowsUpdateClient:21
   I am finding that it's not consistent, I have seen sometime it reboot but most of the time I am not seeing this event after my updates have finished installation but nothing in Event Viewer.
2. One thing I am seeing is following registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Reporting\RebootWatch`

If it's empty then no more reboots are required but trouble is when should I check it.
I am not sure if I can check when wuauclt.exe finishes.

### Edit #1 based on answer by @Map

If I use Setup:4 or Setup:2, they come as many events around the same time. Rebooting or shutting down at the first occurrence would interrupt the remaining

It seems the challenge is to capture when the Windows update is done and Windows Update shows Reboot or Done.

[image: Setup:4 & Setup:2]

Comment: Had a look at [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/02/20/use-powershell-to-find-servers-that-need-a-reboot/) or [this](https://gist.github.com/altrive/5329377)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn`t capture the right Event. Please try to check Windows Logs\Setup.

Usually there will be an Event ID "4" recorded(reboot is needed). Then there will be an event ID "2" recorded which indicates the updates have been installed successfully(trigger to shutdown).

Comment: updated question based on this.